# R studio , how to sum elements in r studio

Tags: r

for a project, I am trying to make a table in ascending order of the regions that have the largest sum of total salaries. So I have to add the values ​​of the salaries that come from the same department (for example I add all the salaries for which the department begins with 37) Can you help me to sum these.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf9Jc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP5Rv.png)

Comment: Please show a small reproducible with `dput`

Comment: how ? what is dput used for? we are 
beginners

Comment: From the image, I didn't see the department column

Comment: this is CD_POSTAL

Comment: Do you want `with(df1, sum(LI_MT_SAT_TOTAL[grepl("^37", CD_POSTAL...3)], na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Yes exactly ! I want to sum the LI_MT_SAT_TOTAL which have the first two values ​​of CD_POSTAL...3 similar

Comment: Ok, then the solution should work

Comment: i have sent you the error's pictures

Comment: I guess you omitted the `with` iin  my code.  it is not `(df1, sum`, but `with(df1, sum(`

Comment: Object DF1 not found !  this is the error now aha ! 
maybe because the CD_POSTAL...3 are characters and not numbers

Comment: ok, have you read the data in `Rstudio`.  What is the object name i.e. I assumed `df1 <- read.csv("yourfile.csv")`   if it is a different object, you need `with(yourobj, ...`

Comment: okay , we have an other error "  invalide type character of argument" the values ​​of CD_POSTAL...3 are not digits, in our array, those are characters. i think it is not working because of this. maybe we can convert them?

Comment: Please show the `dput(head(yourdata, 20))` and your expected output

Comment: i did it on the post :)  new pictures

Comment: we are on discord if you ever agree to chat

Comment: why  can't you post the output for `dput` for first 20 rows instead of making this going on for a long time.  The `dput` gives the same structure of your data and thus I can test it, instead of thinking what your original data column names are or the type of the columns etc?

Comment: I saw your image, but can you copy the output from the image?

Comment: we do not understand  your answer , 
we think we just have to convert the CD_POSTAL...3 elements into numbers. we are lost

Comment: From your image, I assume you want to sum `LI_MT_SAT_TOTAL` based on the substr ing from CD_POSTAL...3 where it starts with 37

Comment: Yes ! but we have "  invalide type character of argument"  when we are using your answer

Comment: perhaps you haven't checked my updated answer `with(fichier_etude_examen, 
   sum(as.numeric(LI_MT_SAT_TOTAL[grepl("^37", CD_POSTAL...3)]), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: It works ! thanks u very much ! 
We will use this code for all the French departments and recover all the sums! We would then like to put them in a table, do you know how ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, we need

```
with(fichier_etude_examen, 
   sum(as.numeric(LI_MT_SAT_TOTAL[grepl("^37", CD_POSTAL...3)]), na.rm = TRUE))
```